# Unable to collate and parse R files (R on Linux)

Tags: linux, r

Something went completely wrong with my R installation. I can't seem to install many of the standard packages on CRAN anymore. For some reason *.Rd files can't be handled.

Just as an example... when I try:

```html
R> install.packages("pbkrtest",dep=TRUE,clean=TRUE)
```

I get this:

```html
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/lang/CRAN/src/contrib/pbkrtest_0.4-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 163079 bytes (159 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 159 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘pbkrtest’ ...
** package ‘pbkrtest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in writeLines(paste0(c(out[is_not_empty]), eor), file) :
  invalid char string in output conversion
Warning in writeLines(paste0(c(out[is_not_empty]), eor), file) :
  invalid char string in output conversion
** R
Warning in readLines(f, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection '/tmp/Rtmph9TUSq/R.INSTALL11f5bfdb46b/pbkrtest/R/KR-Sigma-G2.R'
Warning in readLines(f, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection '/tmp/Rtmph9TUSq/R.INSTALL11f5bfdb46b/pbkrtest/R/KR-across-versions.R'
Warning in readLines(f, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection '/tmp/Rtmph9TUSq/R.INSTALL11f5bfdb46b/pbkrtest/R/KR-linearAlgebra.R'
Warning in readLines(f, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection '/tmp/Rtmph9TUSq/R.INSTALL11f5bfdb46b/pbkrtest/R/KR-vcovAdj.R'
Warning in readLines(f, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection '/tmp/Rtmph9TUSq/R.INSTALL11f5bfdb46b/pbkrtest/R/KR-vcovAdj0.R'
Warning in readLines(f, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection '/tmp/Rtmph9TUSq/R.INSTALL11f5bfdb46b/pbkrtest/R/KR-vcovAdj2-prev.R'
Error in parse(outFile) : 
  /tmp/Rtmph9TUSq/R.INSTALL11f5bfdb46b/pbkrtest/R/modelCoercion.R:172:0: unexpected end of input
170: 
171: 
    ^
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package ‘pbkrtest’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/pbkrtest’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpMLRlv9/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("pbkrtest", dep = TRUE, clean = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
```

I don't understand... I usually can track down issues like this. But this one I don't know. For the record, I can admit that I've fiddled a bit with Bioconductor libraries. But nothing aside from plain installations. And I've used the OpenCPU PPA for r-base installation. Apart from that I'm just a regular user.

Here is my version:

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2014                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        66913                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet
```

And sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

**EDIT**: This is officially weird! I just ran the same command on my (headless) Debian server, from the same mirror as above:

```
R> install.packages('pbkrtest',dep=TRUE,clean=TRUE)
```

The setup is identical to my Mint client...

```
R> version

platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2014                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        66913                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet

R> sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: Did you try with another CRAN repository?

Comment: Yes. I tried a few other mirrors, but no love.

Comment: A recently modified .Rprofile?

Comment: Wow! I just purged my .Rprofile and now everything works smoothly. Very impressive Pascal! You have a fan here...