# ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package - upload to CRAN

Tags: r, devtools, cran

Users encounter the same error message while installing packages in R ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749780/unable-to-collate-and-parse-r-files-r-on-linux) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139808/r-encoding-issues-when-installing-package-from-github)), and the solutions seem to be to switch site mirror or wait for the maintainers to fix the bugs. However, I have the problem with uploading my package to CRAN, and the package created on a Mac does not pass checks on Windows and the developers version of R.

The problematic upload to CRAN is the sixth version of the package and the first time this error appeared.

```
* installing *source* package 'packagename' ...
** using staged installation
** R
Error in parse(outFile) : 
  d:/temp/RtmpGW8fFv/R.INSTALL129d81ef3788f/packagename/R/functionname.R:1:1: unexpected '<'
1: <
    ^
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'packagename'
* removing 'd:/RCompile/CRANguest/R-devel/lib/packagename'
```

I tried displaying invisible characters and there is no "<" anywhere, where it is not supposed to be. Next, I normalized line endings, manually deleted characters at the beginnings of lines and nothing helped.

Does anyone know how to fix the above error from the maintainer's perspective?

**Edit:**
Relevant part of the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Depends: R (>= 3.4.0),
License: GPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports: limSolve,
    quadprog,
    stats,
    graphics,
    grDevices
RoxygenNote: 6.1.1
Suggests: testthat
BuildVignettes: true
```

The function uses `base` commands and `limSolve::linp`.

```
#' Fuzzy Linear Regression using the Fuzzy Least Absolute Residual Method
#'
#' The function calculates fuzzy regression coeficients using the fuzzy least absolute
#' residual (FLAR) method proposed by Zeng et al. (2017) 
#' for non-symmetric triangular fuzzy numbers.
#' @param x matrix with the second to last columns representing independent variable
#'    observations. The first column is related to the intercept, so it consists of ones.
#'    Missing values not allowed.
#' @param y matrix of dependent variable observations. The first column contains the 
#'    central tendency, the second column the left spread and the third column the right
#'    spread of non-symmetric triangular fuzzy numbers. Missing values not allowed.
#' @details The FLAR method expects real value input for the explanatory variables, and 
#'    non-symmetric triangular fuzzy numbers for the response variable. The prediction 
#'    returns non-symmetric triangular fuzzy numbers.
#' @note Preferred use is through the \code{\link{fuzzylm}} wrapper function with argument
#'    \code{method = "flar"}.
#' @inherit fuzzylm return
#' @inherit plrls seealso
#' @references Zeng, W., Feng, Q. and Li, J. (2017) Fuzzy least absolute linear regression. 
#'    \emph{Applied Soft Computing} 52: 1009-1019.
#' @keywords fuzzy
#' @export
#' @examples
#'    data(fuzzydat)
#'    fuzzylm(y ~ x, fuzzydat$dia, "flar", , , "yl", "yl")

flar <- function(x, y){
vars <- colnames(x)
n <- nrow(x)
p <- ncol(x)
X <- x

I <- diag(n)
Ir <- diag(p)
Z <- matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = n)
ZX <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = p)
ZXr <- matrix(0, nrow = p, ncol = p)
Zr <- matrix(0, nrow = p, ncol = n)

f <- c(rep(1, 6*n), rep(0, 3*p))

Req <- cbind(I, -I, Z, Z, Z, Z, X, ZX, ZX)
Req <- rbind(Req, cbind(Z, Z, I, -I, Z, Z, ZX, X, ZX))
Req <- rbind(Req, cbind(Z, Z, Z, Z, I, -I, ZX, ZX, X))

leq <- matrix(c(y))

R <- cbind(-I, Z, Z, Z, Z, Z, ZX, ZX, ZX)
R <- rbind(R, cbind(Z, -I, Z, Z, Z, Z, ZX, ZX, ZX))
R <- rbind(R, cbind(Z, Z, -I, Z, Z, Z, ZX, ZX, ZX))
R <- rbind(R, cbind(Z, Z, Z, -I, Z, Z, ZX, ZX, ZX))
R <- rbind(R, cbind(Z, Z, Z, Z, -I, Z, ZX, ZX, ZX))
R <- rbind(R, cbind(Z, Z, Z, Z, Z, -I, ZX, ZX, ZX))
R <- rbind(R, cbind(Zr, Zr, Zr, Zr, Zr, Zr, ZXr, -Ir, ZXr))
R <- rbind(R, cbind(Zr, Zr, Zr, Zr, Zr, Zr, ZXr, ZXr, -Ir))
R <- rbind(R, cbind(Z, Z, Z, Z, Z, Z, ZX, -X, ZX))
R <- rbind(R, cbind(Z, Z, Z, Z, Z, Z, ZX, ZX, -X))

l <- matrix(rep(0, 8*n + 2*p))

sorig <- limSolve::linp(E = Req, F = leq, G = -R, H = -l, Cost = f, ispos = FALSE)
s <- sorig$X

coefs <- matrix(c(s[(6*n+1):(6*n+p)],
        s[(6*n+p+1):(6*n+2*p)],
        s[(6*n+2*p+1):(6*n+3*p)]), ncol = 3, 
        dimnames = list(vars, c("center", "left.spread", "right.spread")))
lims <- t(apply(x, 2, range))
rownames(lims) <- vars
colnames(lims) <- c("min", "max")
fuzzy <- list(call = NULL, x = x, y = y, lims = lims,
    method = "fls", fuzzynum = "non-symmetric triangular", coef = coefs)
class(fuzzy) <- "fuzzylm"
fuzzy
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the contents of `R/functionname.R` and `DESCRIPTION`?

Comment: is the issue related to installing pkg with devtools? are you getting the same error with R CMD INSTALL on a tar.gz file?

Comment: @jangorecki No. I do not have any issue with the package on my computer (Mac OS 10.14). The problem arrises only with the Windows and devel screen on CRAN, when testing the package upload.

Comment: I'm not sure what's to gain for you here by not including the contents of `R/functionname.R`; it's very difficult for anyone to help you without your code.

Comment: @duckmayr I added the full content of the function file. In the meantime, I worked on the package on multiple computers and operating systems and once upon a time, CRAN accepted the file. I don't know why though and how I fixed that apart from randomly trying different computers. Any suggestions for direct troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a random guess: Does the error also occur with a previous version of roxygen2? Say `6.0.1` or `6.1.0`.

Comment: @SeGa No. The problem did not appear with previous package versions, and arose last week.

Comment: What is your R version?

Comment: @ElieKerArno R 3.6.0

Comment: After some digging, I found that this error was (for me) due to an out of place [comma](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/mde/commit/77df98801662e59cbc0eb7f1e7beca38b7ef548e#commitcomment-44633606).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I found the reason for the problem and the solution. The file with the problematic function was created on Windows (RStudio) and edited on a Mac (BBEdit). The Mac tried to keep the Windows line endings during edits, and upon returning the file to Windows, the encoding changed to a rare variation of UTF8. The R compilers on Windows could not process the exotic encoding.

The solution seems to be to consistently force all line endings to `LF` across platforms and to make sure the file encoding remains stable on different platforms.

Comment: what is the process for converting line endings? I am getting the same error building my package with `devtools`, except I am editing on Windows and I suspect most of these files were written on Mac. I saved all the .R files with UTF-8 encoding. The DESCRIPTION file says "Encoding: UTF-8"

Comment: @eabrown2378 That is correct, but might be insufficient on some OS combinations. When I switch computers, I check the encoding of the individual files manually. Maybe there is a better way, but I did not further pursue it.