# Hmisc package : ERROR in parse(outFile)...unexpected '>'

Tags: r, package, hmisc

I am a beginner in R and I am trying to install arrayQualityMetrics package
there's an error though in the 'Hmisc' dependency
I get this error :

```
Error in parse(outFile) :
/tmp/RtmpkFTuHf/R.INSTALLbd637e8c1e92/Hmisc/R/describe.s:1443:63: unexpected '\>'
1442:  
1443:   b \<- gt::gt(a)                                             |\>
^
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package ‘Hmisc’

* removing ‘/home/mariemchatti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Hmisc’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Hmisc’ had non-zero exit status
```

I searched but couldn't find an answer to this specific error.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04
Rstudio version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

THANKS !

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install the `arrayQualityMetrics` package? Are you running `install.packages("arrayQualityMetrics")`? What happens if you run `install.packages("Hmisc")` first?

Comment: @MrFlick I initially tried to install it using 'BiocManager::install('arrayQualityMetrics')', also using tried 'install.packages("Hmisc")' and got the same error in both scenarios. Using 'install.packages("arrayQualityMetrics")' also didn't work as it tells me it's not available for this R version.

Comment: @shattymariem, what do you get when you type `R.Version()$version.string`? Remember that R and RStudio are two separate things. RStudio is the pretty wrapper around R, the programming language. Even if your RStudio is up-to-date, you may still be running an older version of R. You usually get "not available for this R version" errors when your R (the language that you download from CRAN) is too old for the packages.

Comment: @David Thank you. When I type that, what I get is the following:  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29). so the error "ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'xx' is related to the R version?

Comment: @shattymariem This post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471638/error-unable-to-collate-and-parse-r-files-for-package-upload-to-cran] has a problem similar to yours.  It is possible that it is a version issue since your R hasn't been updated since 2020. I would suggest updating it even if it doesn't solve your problem. Have you been mixing operating systems, such as editing the program on a PC and then running the code in linux?